# What's "keyword control structure" in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, coding-style

In CakeBook Conding Standards page, View Files section ([link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html#view-files)), it's said:

> In view files (.ctp files) developers should use keyword control
>   structures. Keyword control structures are easier to read in complex
>   view files. Control structures can either be contained in a larger PHP
>   block, or in separate PHP tags:

```
<?php
if ($isAdmin):
    echo '<p>You are the admin user.</p>';
endif;
?>
<p>The following is also acceptable:</p>
<?php if ($isAdmin): ?>
    <p>You are the admin user.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know what are control structures, but what's "keyword" control structure?
Sorry for this newbie question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

They are basically saying that you shouldn't use:

```
if(isAdmin()) {
     echo '<p>Hello, Admin</p>';
}
```

For large blocks of conditional HTML, I prefer to use the second method they show. It's much easier to follow than a bunch of echo statements.

Comment: thanks, what about colons instead of brackets? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: If you're using the alternative syntax, the opening keywords need the colon and you don't use the braces. The colon tells the PHP interpreter to look for the end* keyword instead of normal scoping rules (braces or single line).

Comment: As for which I prefer... If I have a case where I'm going to be outputting large blocks of HTML, I'll use the alternative syntax since it is much more readable than a whole series of echo statements. As much as I love CakePHP, I actually would prefer that they natively use a templating system rather than the spaghetti of code and HTML that PHP uses. Not that templates are perfect either.